# Replacing column values that conditionally match a list of values in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to replace values in one dataframe when it matches an identifier in a second dataframe of a much smaller size. A toy example of what I've tried:

```
df1 = data.frame(row = seq(1,6),
                   x = c("a","b","c","d","e","f"))

df2 = data.frame(row = c(5,3,1,15,10),
                 x2 = c("g","h","i","j","k"))

df3 = df1 %>% mutate(x = case_when(
  df1$row == df2$row ~ df2$x2,
  .default = df1$x
))
```

I am attempting this to read, when df1$row matches df2$row, replace df1$x with the value from df2$x2 and otherwise leave df1$x. The expected output:

```
df3
  row x
1   1 i
2   2 b
3   3 h
4   4 d
5   5 g
6   6 f
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `join` by `row`, then use `coalesce`:

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    left_join(df2, by = 'row') %>%
    mutate(x = coalesce(x2, x), .keep = 'unused')

  row x
1   1 i
2   2 b
3   3 h
4   4 d
5   5 g
6   6 f
```

Comment: This works, but I"m not sure how, could you elaborate what coalesce is doing? Also, if you wanted to replace several rows, could you do:
`mutate(x = coalesce(x2,x), y = coalesce(y2,y) ...)`

Comment: coalesce(x,y) replaces NAs in x with corresponding values in y, outputing a vector the same length as x. https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/coalesce.html

Comment: this multiple coalesces are possible, hard to tell without a proper reproducible example. We may be able to come up with a scalable solution if needed.

Answer (score 1):

We might use {powerjoin}

```r
df1 = data.frame(row = seq(1,6),
                 x = c("a","b","c","d","e","f"))

df2 = data.frame(row = c(5,3,1,15,10),
                 x2 = c("g","h","i","j","k"))

library(powerjoin)
power_left_join(df1, df2 |> dplyr::rename(x = x2), by = "row", conflict = coalesce_yx)
#>   row x
#> 1   1 i
#> 2   2 b
#> 3   3 h
#> 4   4 d
#> 5   5 g
#> 6   6 f
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-17 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

With dplyr 1.1.0:

```
df1 %>%
  rows_update(df2 %>% rename(x = x2), unmatched = "ignore")
```

Result

```
Matching, by = "row"
  row x
1   1 i
2   2 b
3   3 h
4   4 d
5   5 g
6   6 f
```

If both tables had the same rownames it would be simpler:

```
df1 %>%
  rows_update(df2, unmatched = "ignore")
```

Comment: This works for the example I created, but in my larger dataset it flags an error because some of the columns I am trying to replace have duplicate values.

Comment: I wonder if that might be resolved if you ran `df1 %>% rows_update(distinct(df2), unmatched = "ignore")`. You might need to specify the columns from df2 you want to keep, if there are additional columns that vary which you don't want distinct copies of.